# Ticketit not working after installation (Invalid JSON Response)

Tags: php, json, ticket-system

I just installed the ticket system [ticketit](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit), but am getting an error immediately when accessing the tickets, saying:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

Also (because I thought it might be just a warning), I tried to create a ticket, but it seems like I get a problem sending a mail, the message says:

```
ErrorException in dc81073f31b304a589fe02cb835417b554e048bd.php line 22:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: \vendor\kordy\ticketit\src\Views\emails\assigned.blade.php)
```

I completed the installation and everything seems to "look" okay, but I still get the error...
BTW: It seems like the 2 tickets I tried to create where created, at least I can find two table entries in the table ticketit...

Any ideas, why this could happen?

Comment: Did you check the page mentioned in the first error?

Comment: @PatrickQ I did check this (https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1) but it doesn't help me...There's just one XHR request, returning Status Code 200